# How to append existing MongoDB collection with aggregation $out operator?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have MongoDB 4.0 Atlas instance, and I need to append results of the aggregation to existing collection without deleting existing items.

I need something like "mode: replaceDocuments" in $out, but this mode will be availiable only in MongoDB 4.2

What I'm trying to get:

Source 1 - existing collection "A":

```
[{ "_id": "id_1", "a": 1 },
 { "_id": "id_2", "a": 2 }]
```

Source 2 — aggregation result data:

```
[{ "_id": "id_3", "a": 3 },
 { "_id": "id_4", "a": 4 }]
```

Result — added data to existing collection "A":

```
[{ "_id": "id_1", "a": 1 },
 { "_id": "id_2", "a": 2 },
 { "_id": "id_3", "a": 3 },
 { "_id": "id_4", "a": 4 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

In [MongoDB v4.2](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community) (currently v4.2.0-rc1), you can utilise [Aggregation Pipeline $merge stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) to append to an existing collection.

The `$merge` stage:

- Can output to a collection in the same or different database.
- Creates a new collection if the output collection does not already exist.
- Can incorporate results (insert new documents, merge documents, replace documents, keep existing documents, fail the operation, process documents with a custom update pipeline) into an existing collection.
- Can output to a sharded collection. Input collection can also be sharded.

For your example, you can do as below:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([ ...., 
               { "$merge" : { into: "A" } } // Has to be the last stage in the pipeline
 ]);
```

See also [Comparison with $out](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#merge-out-comparison)

There are many use cases for `$merge`:

- [On-Demand Materialized View: Initial Creation](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#on-demand-materialized-view-initial-creation)
- [On-Demand Materialized View: Update/Replace Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#on-demand-materialized-view-update-replace-data)
- [Only Insert New Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#only-insert-new-data)
- [Merge Results from Multiple Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#merge-results-from-multiple-collections)
- [Use the Pipeline to Customize the Merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#use-the-pipeline-to-customize-the-merge)